# Series of video lectures on the subject of Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, online-resources

I am looking for a series of video lectures on the subject of complex analysis which follow Conway's text *Functions of Complex Variable I*. Any recommendations?

Comment: That's a fantastic text for complex variables. I'm going to be watching this for answers!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what text, if any, he follows but you could learn a lot watching [Steven J. Miller's lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfrIk13rAJ4).